# Add ".00" to an integer BigDecimal in Java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Given an integer `BigDecimal` (i.e., with no decimal point), how can I add `.00` to it?

What I have is:

```
BigDecimal Add2Zeros(BigDecimal num)
{
    return num.divide(BigDecimal.ONE,2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
}
```

But it seems a bit clumsy. Is there a better / simpler / cleaner way to do that?

BTW, It is not supposed to have any impact on the argument, except for the `toString()` result.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.setScale()`:

```
return num.setScale(2);
```

Note that it will NOT truncate numbers; if a number has *more* than 2 decimals, it will throw an `ArithmeticException`. (except if all decimals after the second one are 0)

Comment: `setScale()` name is misleading because it returns a new `BigDecimal`, it doesn't "set" the scale. Think of it as `withScale()` which would make more sense.

Comment: @ryvantage yeah, the `BigDecimal` API is not a model of good design ;) But it's too late to change that... Although the OP may want to use apfloat instead

Comment: Oops. Tried it before and it didn't work; probably forgot to assign the new result into the original argument... Thanks :)

Comment: @barakmanos if you work with big numbers a lot, consider giving a go at apfloat